Caius won't talk to me following the death and subsequent resurrection on Divayath Fyr
I killed Divayth to grab his dagger, and when I saw the notification on the bottom of the screen I used console command to revive him. Caius still will not talk to me.
Are there any console commands that will make him talk to me?

I don't know about console commands, but a footnote in the UESP wiki suggests that he'll talk to you if you have a bounty of 1000 or more.
